# How to cast this integer value to date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

i have airbnb data and i want to cast column last_reviews (which datatype is int) to date
this is my sql code http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5ea42/31

how do i cast int > date?
or how do i create last_reviews column as datatype date?

Comment: last_review clearly has a value in int. you can see the values at the bottom of pannel.

Comment: You should anonymize the data.

Comment: Can you give a reference to which date you want to show for which int-value ?  What datetime should be shown when last_review=43434 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last_review date seems to be the number of days since 1900-01-01 so in MySQL you would:

```
SELECT '1900-01-01' + INTERVAL last_review DAY AS last_review_date
FROM ...
```

The result checks out for the sample data (which you should delete).

Answer (score 1):

`last_review` values looks like VB(A) numeric representation for dates. If so then test this:

```sql
SELECT last_review, '1900-01-01' + INTERVAL last_review DAY
FROM airbnb
```

Adjust constant part (maybe it must be `'1899-12-31'`?) if needed.